# re.findall return separate non-overlapping results

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, findall

I am new to Python and I am struggling a bit with regular expressions. If I have an input like this:

```
    text = <tag>xyz</tag>\n<tag>abc</tag>
```

Is it possible to get an output list with elements like:

```
    matches = ['<tag>xyz</tag>','<tag>abc</tag>]
```

Right now I am using the following regex

```
    matches = re.findall(r"<tag>[\w\W]*</tag>", text)
```

But instead of a list with two elements I am getting only one element with the whole input string like:

```
    matches = ['<tag>xyz</tag>\n<tag>abc</tag>']
```

Could someone please guide me?
Thank you.

Comment: Use lazy (or non-greedy) quantifier, replace `*` with `*?`.

Comment: I am new to regex and wasn't really aware of the greedy and non-greedy search. Thank you for linking those answers. But `*?` is returning only the last occurrence. Is there a way to capture all occurrences?

Comment: It returns all occurrences.

Comment: This is my exact code `matches = re.findall(r"<paragraph>[\w\W]*?</paragraph>", file1)` . Am I doing something wrong that is making it return only the last occurrence? I am trying to capture the data between multiple `<paragraph>` and `</paragraph>` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make your capture non-greedy.

Change this regex,

```
<tag>[\w\W]*</tag>
```

to

```
<tag>[\w\W]*?</tag>


import re
text = '<tag>xyz</tag>\n<tag>abc</tag>'
matches = re.findall(r"<tag>[\w\W]*?</tag>", text)
print(matches)
```

Prints,

```
['<tag>xyz</tag>', '<tag>abc</tag>']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But doing that is giving me only the last occurrence of that pattern instead of all occurrences. Could you please suggest a way to capture all occurrences?

Comment: @ApoorvaPatil: Try my python code in my answer. It prints exactly what I have written there. If it's not working for you, can you edit your post and share the code you are trying?